# Async webrequest with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

**Hi,**

I have a simple ASP.NET MVC C# webpage that users can submit Title, Descirption, Tags and a link(URL). The post to the service is sent with JASON(AJAX) and works great for the most part. But sometimes the post just hangs and nothing happens when this happens it will also be vary slow to load any other page of this website.

The webmethod is real simple, first it stored the data to the database and then it uses HttpWebRequest to fetch the URL page. The fetched page is then read(header data) and in most cases it stores a image.

I suspect that the hangig is due to HttpWebRequest taking to long. The request method starts with this :

```
if (url != null && url.Length > 0)
                {
                    request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

                    dirInfo.Create();

                    request.UserAgent = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DomainName"];
                    webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.BeginGetResponse( .GetResponse();
                    if (webresponse.ContentType.StartsWith("image/"))
                    {
                        using (WebClient tmpClient = new WebClient())
                        {
                            client.DownloadFile(url, postThumbnailsTemp + "\\" + fileName);
                        }

                        if (SavePostImage(postThumbnailsTemp + "\\" + fileName, postId))
                            return true;
                    }


                    if (webresponse.ContentType.StartsWith("text/html") || webresponse.ContentType.StartsWith("application/xhtml"))
                    {
                          var resultStream = webresponse.GetResponseStream();
                          doc.Load(resultStream);
```

The question is if it might be better to use a async call here? Like the HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse? This would mean that the user might be redirected to the post page before the URL webpage is read and stored.

Comment: I'm unclear on that the problem is. "might be better" better in what regard? Is your code working right now? What do you want to improve?

Comment: As I said "sometimes the post just hangs and nothing happens when this happens it will also be vary slow to load any other page of this website." And im sure that this have to do with the webrequest code.

Comment: So your question is "why does this POST hang and how to fix it?". There is no information here that would allow to find the problem. Is the remote server just not responding? In that case fix the server. Use Fiddler to find out.

Comment: Thats the problem, it is far from always and I have not been able to recreate the problem manually on my own server. It only happens at the host but there is also alot more trafic. Becouse all other operations is vary simple I am sure that the problem is within the code I posted. A better way to go would maybe be async webrequest but im also not sure that this solves the problem. I am using Elmah for exception logging but this does never throw any exception it just hangs and makes all other calls slow.

Comment: Async would either also wait, or you would not have the result when you send the response. Both is likely to be unacceptable to you. Try to create a small repro case with a minimal number of lines of code. Maybe request the URL in a loop until it "hangs".

Comment: Yes, but it would be okay if I did not get the result until later when the page was fetched. But you are probably right, I should try to recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using web api for example, you can change your api controller action to be async.
If you do so, the response will NOT return to the client until the task has completed but it will also not block other client/threads!

Example

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]MyObject obj)
```

Within the method you should also use the async await pattern to create your custom request...

Have some articles for further information of how to build async web apis

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/09/18/scaffolding-asynchronous-mvc-and-web-api-controllers-for-entity-framework-6.aspx

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=948

and maybe watch [this video](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/async-and-await)

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? Maby you got an article to read more on about this?

Comment: Sure, added some links to the answer